# Getting error message when trying to attach a class to an object

Tags: python, class, methods

i have a little problem when i try to attach a class to an object in python. I have a textfile 'file', which is seperated into a list for each line. The program will read every line and print a name and a longname. Imagine that the textfile look like this:

"John '\n' John Travolta" (...)

Here's my bit of code:

```
class Name:
  def __init__(self, name, longname):
   self.name=name
   self.longname=longname
  def __str__(self):
   s="Name:"+self.name
   s+="\n Longname:"+self.longname
  def func():
   for line in file:
       name=line[:1]
       longname=line['\n':]
c=Name(name, longname)
c.func()
```

I get the error message that my 'name' and 'longname' is not defined but I did this with my function??? :(

It works if I put the function outside the class, like this:

```
def func():
 for line in file:
  name=line[:1]
  longname=line['\n':]
  c=Name(name, longname)
  print c
```

Need help!

Comment: i assume when you say  `'name' and 'shortname' is not defined` you mean that `name` and `longname` are not defined.

Comment: yes i mean 'longname'. yes homework problem and this is not even the real problem, im just trying to explain a problem within my program with an example

Comment: Please use four space indentation in the future so it is easier for us to read your code. I'm not sure what your problem is at this point; you seem to have solved it. That function should be outside the class, a static method, or you need to redesign the class. Why can't it be outside the class, and instead of `print`ing `c`, `return c` then do `c = func()` instead of `c = Name...` and `c.func()`?

Comment: I tried to return c, and then do the c=func() and c.func, but it just says that 'Name' is not an attribute for func(), which makes sense i guess because func is outside the class. Thanks for the help though,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign something to name and longname before you can use them:

```
name = 'foo'
longname = 'foo bar'
c=Name(name, longname)
c.func()
```

---

> but I did this with my function?

No.

- Firstly, you didn't call your function yet. The function call is *after* the line that gives the error.
- Secondly, the function has its own scope. The `name` there is different from the global `name`.

I don't think it makes any sense to move your `func` method inside the class definition. The code that you said works is a better way to do it.

Comment: Yes i see what you mean, but the problem is I dont know what name and longname is b4 the function has read my textfile. Though imagine if I have to use the names and longnames for each person later on - what can i do then? return c at the end of my function?

Comment: @John: Store your name objects in a list.